# returning JSON response to a ajax call prompts file download containing the response

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

i am submitting a from using jQuery ajax, and server is returning json response. but instead of the script, parsing the json result, the browser is prompting me to download the json response.

I have had this problem before, where i forgot to return false at the end of the event handler. But this time im clueless why this is happening.
anyone has experienced this problem.. 
thanks

Comment: Specifically, what your server is doing in the output.

Comment: What HTTP headers is the server returning in the response?

Comment: I am sorry, i found the problem. i was doing something stupid .. sorry again

Comment: Care to post details? Maybe other people could learn from the same issue.

Comment: You should post your "stupid" mistake in case someone else makes the same stupid mistake in the future;)

Comment: it was a script reference problem.. 
@phoebuc-- if u dont have anything better to post, dont post at all.. if my mistake was something other people could learn from i would have posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser is trying to download a file, it most probably related to `content-type` of your response. You are using something that the browser considers to be binary and unsafe. Try using `text/plain, text/html, text/xml` or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

After some stumbling around, I solved my problem by including links to the following two jquery libs:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```